# Can you help me get rid of an intermediary output in my imagemagick convert commands?

Tags: bash, imagemagick-convert

I have the following `convert` command in bash.

```
    convert "$WALLPAPER1" -resize "${H[0]}"x"${V[0]}"^ -gravity center -crop "${H[0]}"x"${V[0]}"+0+0 "$WALLPAPERS/.temp1.jpg"
    convert "$WALLPAPER2" -resize "${H[1]}"x"${V[1]}"^ -gravity center -crop "${H[1]}"x"${V[1]}"+0+0 jpg:- |
    convert "$WALLPAPERS/.temp1.jpg" - +append "$WALLPAPERS/.temp.jpg"
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the `"$WALLPAPERS/.temp1.jpg"` intermediary?  So is there a way to carry over the output of the first `convert` over to the input of the third `convert`?

Comment: maybe you can use `process-groups`, like `{ convert WP1 ... ; convert WP2 ...; } | convert WP/temp1.jpg -  ...` ? Process-groups (defined inside of `{ ...; ...; ...n;}`) combine all std-output and present it to the next reader in the pipeline. Good luck.

Comment: Interesting... I found a way writing my intermediaries to *memory-program-registers* calling convert only once.  I will look into `process-groups` and try and see which is more efficient && intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
convert "$WALLPAPER1" -resize "${H[0]}"x"${V[0]}"^ -gravity center -crop "${H[0]}"x"${V[0]}"+0+0 -write mpr:temp1 +delete \
"$WALLPAPER2" -resize "${H[1]}"x"${V[1]}"^ -gravity center -crop "${H[1]}"x"${V[1]}"+0+0 -write mpr:temp2 +delete \
-gravity north mpr:temp1 mpr:temp2 +append "$WALLPAPERS/.temp.jpg"
```

There was no need to have 3 convert calls.  Instead of writing to file you can write to *memory-program-register* (mpr) and then recall later.  The `+delete` deletes the original image.